# Prove $(1+2/x)^{ -1}= x/x+2 = x/2(1+x/2)^{ -1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-theorem

Prove $(1+2/x)^{ -1}= x/x+2 = x/2(1+x/2)^{ -1}$ I am stuck on this question I do not know how these three are related and tried working it out but got no where i will attack some of my work.And none of my collages know how to solve it  Any help is much-appricated. thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0,-2\},$
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{x}} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{x}} \times \frac{x}{x} = \frac{x}{x+2}$$
$$\frac{x}{2} \times \frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{x}{2\times(1+\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{x}{2+x}$$

Comment: This is the second line if I read your parentheses right

Comment: I am sorry I read it wrong then immediately deleted the comment. but thank you very much! It was very use full!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE!

Here are some hints:

$(1+2/x)^{-1} = \frac{1}{1+2/x} = \frac{1}{x/x+2/x} = \frac{1}{(x+2)/x} = \frac{x}{x+2}$ which is related to your 2nd expression (but in yours the parentheses are missing).

Here is the other equality:

$\frac{x}{2}\cdot (1+x/2)^{-1} = \frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{1+x/2} = \frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2/2+x/2} = \frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{(x+2)/2} = \frac{x}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{x+2} = \frac{x}{x+2}$

Comment: Thank you very much! I see how you did the second one but the The third one is $x/2(1+x/2)^{ -1}$ and I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: See added comment.

Comment: owwww i seee thank you very much I really appreciate it!